# How to parse a 7GB file, with Data.ByteString?

Tags: parsing, haskell, readfile, bytestring

I have to parse a file, and indeed a have to read it first, here is my program :

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import System.Environment    

main = do
 args      <- getArgs
 let path  =  args !! 0
 content   <- B.readFile path
 let lines = B.lines content
 foobar lines 

 foobar :: [B.ByteString] -> IO()
 foobar _ = return ()
```

but, after the compilation

```
> ghc --make -O2 tmp.hs
```

the execution goes through the following error when called with a 7Gigabyte file.

```
> ./tmp  big_big_file.dat
> tmp: {handle: big_big_file.dat}: hGet: illegal ByteString size (-1501792951): illegal operation
```

thanks for any reply!

Comment: @DanielFischer what do you call `platform` ? if It is the Operating system, then I'm using Linux ubuntu 10.4. Thanks

Comment: 32 bit or 64? In general a 32bit OS is going to have problems with files that big.

Comment: @DanielFischer, 32 bits.

Comment: `ByteString`s use `Int`s on all platforms, so they only support up to 2 gigabytes. You need to use [lazy `ByteString`s](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html) for it to work.

Comment: @dflemstr: With GHC, `Int` is 64 bits on 64-bit architectures.

Comment: @ehird, yes but it is only guaranteed to have 30 bits, so if you want to make cross-platform applications, you should use the least common denominator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strict `ByteString`s only support up to 2 GiB of memory. You need to use [lazy `ByteString`s](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html) for it to work.

Comment: Whaou ! Thank @dflemstr It work, just by changing `Data.ByteString.Char8` to `Data.Bytestring.Lazy.Char8` as you said.

Answer (score 9):

The length of `ByteString`s are `Int`. If `Int` is 32 bits, a 7GB file will exceed the range of `Int` and the buffer request will be for a wrong size and can easily request a negative size.

The code for `readFile` converts the file size to `Int` for the buffer request

```
readFile :: FilePath -> IO ByteString
readFile f = bracket (openBinaryFile f ReadMode) hClose
    (\h -> hFileSize h >>= hGet h . fromIntegral)
```

and if that overflows, an "illegal ByteString size" error or a segmentation fault are the most likely outcomes.

If at all possible, use lazy `ByteString`s to handle files that big. In your case, you pretty much have to make it possible, since with 32 bit `Int`s, a 7GB `ByteString` is impossible to create.

If you need the lines to be strict `ByteString`s for the processing, and no line is exceedingly long, you can go through lazy `ByteString`s to achieve that

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LC
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

main = do
    ...
    content <- LC.readFile path
    let llns = LC.lines content
        slns = map (C.concat . LC.toChunks) llns
    foobar slns
```

but if you can modify your processing to deal with lazy `ByteString`s, that will probably be better overall.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer! It is clear to me now, but what can I do to parse my file ?

Comment: Since you split it into lines, if you are sure that no line is longer than 2GB, you can read the file as a lazy `ByteString`, split that into lines and if necessary, make a strict `ByteString` from each line. Or you can read the file line-by-line. Needs more info to determine the best approach (but probably going through lazy it is).